# SharePoint Online Custom Features

Tags: sharepoint-online, feature-activation

Is there any way to create custom features that can be deployed and activated/deactivated at the site level?

From re-searching it I don't think it is possible, but thought I should ask in here just in case I'm missing something.

**Edit - Some more info:** An example might be a custom ribbon element that would only appear in the ribbon if the feature is enabled. In 2010 we would use site features activation as a way of toggling on/off a piece of customization. In 2010 we were able to deploy FTC solutions, whereas we can't in SPO, so I'm curious to know if there is a way to do something similar?

When I create a SharePoint Add-In, and I include a list, content type, app part (etc) to the solution, I see they appear under "Feature1" but it is scoped at the 'Web' level, so when it is deployed to my site I don't see the feature under the site features page.

[image]

Comment: can you please give some more information on it (If possible than with example)?

Comment: Updated question with more info.

Comment: Hello Ryan, Is my answer helps you to understand the concept of Feature receiver for **SharePoint Add-Ins**?

Comment: I am happy that my answer helps you... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only Web is permitted for Features in SharePoint Add-ins** (both host web Features and Features inside a .wsp in an add-in package).

Add-in scope should also not be confused with add-in permission levels. SharePoint Add-ins can request permissions to all or selected parts of SharePoint content at the levels of list, web, site collection, and tenancy. Installing an add-in with tenant scope does not give it permissions that it would not otherwise have, nor does it cancel key provisions of the SharePoint security model. For more information about add-in permissions, see [Add-in permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx).

This is the limitation of Microsoft which can't be overcome in SharePoint.

You can get more information from following link.

[Tenancies and deployment scopes for SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179896.aspx)